# Average Correlation Coefficient

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics

I have 20 sets of 5 data points, and I am plotting them all on the same figure. I am looking at blood flow signals and estimating a quantity from them. X is the variability (i.e. the variance) in the blood flow signal, and Y is the resulting confidence interval size in the estimate from that signal. There are 5 signals for each individual recorded on different days, and I am trying to determine if variability of the signal affects variability of the estimate.

I want to find the overall correlation coefficient and significance of the correlation, based on each sets correlation. I can't take all the data points and find one correlation from those because it implies the opposite correlation to what is actually present (see the picture, the black line is if I take the overall of all the data, the coloured is each data sets correlation).

How do I go about finding the overall correlation based on each sets correlation? Is there some form of average correlation, and if so, how do I extract a significance from this average correlation?

[image]

Comment: Are each of the different colored sets (not black) associated with a particular level of a categorical variable?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, they are simply results from a different individual. 20 individuals, 5 tests per individual. Trying to find the change per individual and thus the overall change in a population

Comment: I'm deleting my answer due to your comment there, which I'm quoting here.  I don't have time to get into a problem of this complexity, and someone else needs to respond.  I believe you need to update your question with this information.

Comment: Here's your comment to my deleted answer: "I am looking at blood flow signals and estimating a quantity from them. X is the variability (i.e. the variance) in the blood flow signal, and Y is the resulting confidence interval size in the estimate from that signal. There are 5 signals for each individual recorded on different days, and I am trying to determine if variability of the signal affects variability of the estimate."